# Why isn't my Dockerfile build copying all of my files into the container?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I am building a docker image of gPodder using an X11 GUI base image. I've gotten the docker container to build and work perfectly fine except for one issue. I would like to use my own modified extension scripts, so I have added these to my docker repository in a directory `root/config/extensions` and COPY this directory into my image in my Dockerfile, however, the extension scripts are never added to the container. At the same time a startup.sh script that is located in the base of my container repository is copied into the container.

I've tried a number of different file structures to add these scripts into the container (including both COPY and ADD), but none have worked. I have tried running two COPY commands (one for the startup.sh script and one for the extensions directory) and one COPY command (`COPY root/ /` - with both the startup.sh script and extensions directory in one `root` directory in the root of the container reposiory).

The entire docker container repository can be seen here: https://github.com/xthursdayx/docker-gpodder

But here is a simplified version of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM hurricane/dockergui:x11rdp1.3

ENV GPODDER_HOME /config
ENV GPODDER_EXTENSIONS /config/extensions
ENV GPODDER_DOWNLOAD_DIR /downloads

RUN \
echo "############ Installing gPodder ##################" && \
apt-get install -y -q gpodder && \
apt-get clean && \
mkdir -p /config/extensions && \
chown -R nobody:users /config && \
chmod -R g+rw /config

COPY root/ /

VOLUME ["/downloads","$GPODDER_HOME","GPODDER_HOME/extensions"]

EXPOSE 8080 3389
```

I have also tried to alter the COPY line as follows:

```
COPY extensions/ /config/extensions/
COPY startapp.sh /startapp.sh
```

Any ideas what my problem is?

Comment: in container you have whole filesystem in `/` and your command `COPY root/ /` just tries to rewrite it. It is the same as you would do `rm -rf /` and containers need working networking, shell and so on to work properly and that is also stored in `/` ... i would try this `COPY root/ /my_root`

Comment: Shouldn't `COPY directory/ /` just copy the contents of the `directory` to the root of the container's file system? As I mentioned, the container works fine and its file system is intact, so doesn't seem to have been rewritten like `rm`. Also as mentioned above, I have also used the code `COPY extensions/ /config/extensions` but that also hasn't worked.